# merge and replace the duplicate value using R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidy

i have 2 dataframe and want to combine, but if there are same value must to replace it to NA, example

```
df1=data.frame(x1=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2),x2=c("a","a","b","b","c","c","c"),x3=c("t","u","v","w","x","y","z"),x4=c("apple","apple","mango","mango","mango","mango","mango"))
```

```
df2=data.frame(x1=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2),x2=c("a","a","a","b","b","b","c","c"),x3=c("t","u","u","v","w","x","y","z"),x5=c("apple A","apple A","apple B","mango A","mango B","mango A","mango A","mango A"),x6=c(10,10,20,10,10,30,30,30))
```

my expected df

```
df3=data.frame(x1=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2),x2=c("a","a","a","b","b","b","c","c"),x3=c("t","u","u","v","w","x","y","z"),x4=c("apple","apple","apple","mango","mango","mango","mango","mango"),x5=c("apple A","apple A","apple B","mango A","mango B","mango A","mango A","mango A"),x6=c(10,NA,20,10,10,30,30,NA))
```

merge df1 and df2, but if df2 had duplicated values on x1,x2 and x5, x6 is NA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider doing:

```
is.na(df2$x6) <- duplicated(df2[c('x1' , 'x2', 'x5', 'x6')])
merge(df1, df2, all.x = TRUE)

  x1 x2 x3    x4      x5 x6
1  1  a  t apple apple A 10
2  1  a  u apple apple A NA
3  1  a  u apple apple B 20
4  1  b  v mango mango A 10
5  2  b  w mango mango B 10
6  2  c  x mango    <NA> NA
7  2  c  y mango mango A 30
8  2  c  z mango mango A NA
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)

df2 %>% 
  mutate(x6 = ifelse(duplicated(pick(c(x1, x2, x5))), NA, x6)) %>% 
  left_join(df1, ., multiple = "all")
```

Note: the use of `left_join(df1, .)` is so that the columns in `df1` come first, otherwise you could simply use `right_join(df1)` if the column order does not matter.

**Output**

```
  x1 x2 x3    x4      x5 x6
1  1  a  t apple apple A 10
2  1  a  u apple apple A NA
3  1  a  u apple apple B 20
4  1  b  v mango mango A 10
5  2  b  w mango mango B 10
6  2  c  x mango    <NA> NA
7  2  c  y mango mango A 30
8  2  c  z mango mango A NA
```